# How do you ask Siri to message whatsapp group?

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

I know the new IOS allows you to ask Siri to send a whatsapp message to a person, can Siri message a whatsapp group ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out today how to do it.

First, you need to be sure that the name of the group can be easily understand by Siri. As I know from myself some group names are too complex for Siri. It will be simple if the group name is like a person's name.

Second, you need to add the group name to your contacts without any number etc. just create a new empty person with the group name.

Answer (score 2):

Due to SiriKit API limitation, Siri can send a message only to a sigle "entity", which could be a contact or an existing group but, actually, you can't write a message to multiple entities in a single action.